# How to toggle or code the Placeholder / Watermark Property on a textbox in Bunifu UI

Tags: vb.net, bunifu

I can't somehow find the property for putting a watermark or a placeholder on a textbox using Bunifu UI. I need it for credential textboxes. I found a source code which only works on a normal textbox but not on Bunifu Textbox.

Here is my code :

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

Public Class Login

Private Sub Login_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Me.CenterToParent()

    BunifuTextbox2._TextBox.PasswordChar = "*"
    SetCueText(BunifuTextbox1, "Username")
    SetCueText(BunifuTextbox2, "Password")
End Sub

Private Sub BunifuTextbox1_OnTextChange(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BunifuTextbox1.OnTextChange

End Sub
End Class

Public Module CueBannerText
<DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet:=CharSet.Auto)> _
Private Function SendMessage(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal msg As Integer, ByVal wParam As Integer, <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)> ByVal lParam As String) As Int32
End Function
Private Declare Function FindWindowEx Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowExA" (ByVal hWnd1 As IntPtr, ByVal hWnd2 As IntPtr, ByVal lpsz1 As String, ByVal lpsz2 As String) As IntPtr
Private Const EM_SETCUEBANNER As Integer = &H1501


Public Sub SetCueText(cntrl As Control, text As String)
    If TypeOf cntrl Is Bunifu.Framework.UI.BunifuDropdown Then
        Dim Edit_hWnd As IntPtr = FindWindowEx(cntrl.Handle, IntPtr.Zero, "Edit", Nothing)
        If Not Edit_hWnd = IntPtr.Zero Then
            SendMessage(Edit_hWnd, EM_SETCUEBANNER, 0, text)
        End If
    ElseIf TypeOf cntrl Is Bunifu.Framework.UI.BunifuTextbox Then
        SendMessage(cntrl.Handle, EM_SETCUEBANNER, 0, text)
    End If
End Sub
End Module
```

HERE IS THE ORIGINAL SOURCE CODE I FOUND :

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

Public Class Form1

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
   SetCueText(TextBox1, "Enter Name here")
End Sub
End Class

Public Module CueBannerText
<DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet:=CharSet.Auto)> _
Private Function SendMessage(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal msg As Integer, ByVal wParam As Integer, <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)> ByVal lParam As String) As Int32
End Function
Private Declare Function FindWindowEx Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowExA" (ByVal hWnd1 As IntPtr, ByVal hWnd2 As IntPtr, ByVal lpsz1 As String, ByVal lpsz2 As String) As IntPtr
Private Const EM_SETCUEBANNER As Integer = &H1501


Public Sub SetCueText(cntrl As Control, text As String)
   If TypeOf cntrl Is ComboBox Then
        Dim Edit_hWnd As IntPtr = FindWindowEx(cntrl.Handle, IntPtr.Zero, "Edit", Nothing)
        If Not Edit_hWnd = IntPtr.Zero Then
            SendMessage(Edit_hWnd, EM_SETCUEBANNER, 0, text)
        End If
    ElseIf TypeOf cntrl Is TextBox Then
        SendMessage(cntrl.Handle, EM_SETCUEBANNER, 0, text)
    End If
End Sub
End Module
```

Comment: Aim your Google at `cue banner`  It is available from the Windows API

Comment: @Plutonix what google? The site? And what’s a cue banner? Is this available to Bunifu?

Comment: If you do like @Plutonix suggested and google it you would find the answers to your questions.

Comment: @VisualVincent yeah I get it a second ago. Thanks though

Comment: To answer your last question: Bunifu is built on top of Windows Forms, so anything that works with WinForms should work with Bunifu as well.

Comment: @VisualVincent should it normally be a single statement code like textbox.text=“” ? Cause most basic properties are single statement codes

Comment: The cue banner isn't implemented in WinForms by default (so the answer to that specific question is **no**), but you can add it on your own thanks to that it is available in the Windows API and the WinForms text boxes are based on the native ones. Google will help you find examples showing how to.

Comment: @VisualVincent I found a source code. But it only works on a normal textbox but not on Bunifu Textbox. I edited the post and showed my code compared to the source code I found

Comment: The `BunifuTextBox` has a property/field called `_TextBox` that points to the underlying WinForms text box, right?

Comment: @VisualVincent  yes, but I don’t notice any property about a cue banner there

Comment: No, as I said it isn't built-in. But you now have a piece if code to set a cue banner for a **regular** text box, and there **is** a regular text box _**inside**_ the BunifuTextBox, sooo...

Comment: @VisualVincent I tried to change the control in the code which says textbox to bunifu textbox but it’s still not showing the cue banner

Comment: I don't believe this... The code is written for a **regular** WinForms text box, and the BunifuTextBox is built **around** such a text box which you can access via the `_TextBox` field - Just change the code to make it set the cue banner of the underlying WinForms text box instead!

Comment: @VisualVincent I tried it by changing it yesterday, you can check the code I posted compared to the source code I got. I tried both and it didn’t work

Comment: Let me just write an answer instead...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted the `BunifuTextBox` contains a regular WinForms text box. The code you found was designed for such a text box, thus all you need to do is set the cue banner for ***the underlying text box*** of the `BunifuTextBox`:

```
SetCueText(BunifuTextbox1._TextBox, "Username")
```

(this uses the original `SetCueText()` code that you found)